# ORACLE DATETIME ROUND UP WHEN MINUTES <> 0

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I have a datetime:

```
select to_date(to_char(r.DATETIMEUTC,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATETIME_UTC,
       round(r.DATETIMEUTC, 'hh') as rounded
from   PROD.WX_RAW r;
```

I need to round up just when the minutes are different to 00.

Example:

1/1/2000 2:37:00 AM => should be => 1/1/2000 3:00:00 AM. (dont round up if hour =00)
1/1/2000 2:00:00 AM => should be => 1/1/2000 2:00:00 AM

For now my code has round function but this one look the nearest hour, I need even if minutes are 15, round up the hour, except when the minutes are 00 in that case I need to keep the hour.

Regards

Comment: What if the minutes is 0 but the seconds is non-zero?  Would 2:00:01 be rounded to 2:00:00 or to 3:00:00?

Comment: just using minutes as reference

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what that means.  Are you completely ignoring seconds?  Or does "minutes <> 0" really mean "the date is not exactly on the hour"?

Comment: ignoring seconds, all the records has seconds on 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd truncate the `date` to the hour and then use a `case` statement to decide whether to add an hour.

```
trunc( r.DATETIMEUTC, 'HH24' ) -- truncate to the hour
+ case when to_number( to_char( r.DATETIMEUTC, 'HH24' ) ) != 0
       then interval '1' hour
       else null
    end
```

Comment: hI Justin, I need to round up the hour, example 1/1/2000 2:37:00 AM to 1/1/2000 3:00:00 AM, not the minutes, if the datetime has 1 to 59 minutes hour up hour, also put the minutes in 00 once has round up

Comment: @Webb - Sorry, I copied and pasted from a version that was for minutes.  Updated

Comment: `to_number(to_char))` is not very appealing; `extract(hour from ...)` seems more natural. Even more natural, change the comparison condition to `when datetimeutc != trunc(datetimeutc, 'hh') then ...` Note also that your formula has a glaring mistake: the `else` part should be `interval '0' hour`, if you add `null` to anything the result is `null`. (You might think that `0` would also work in the `else` clause, but it wouldn't - the values in the `case` expression must be of the same data type, one can't be an interval while the other is a number.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `datetimeutc` is the input value, of `date` data type, you can do something like this:

```
select trunc(datetimeutc + interval '59' minute, 'hh')
from   .....
```

The math is pretty simple, but most programmers won't trust the math anyway; they will use the formula on a few examples to convince themselves it's correct. So I won't bother with the formal proof.